# Managing a ForeignKey Relation in Django Admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I am using django to create an inventory management system. There are two models ***store*** and ***retailer***. Each ***retailer*** can only work in one ***store***, but each ***store*** can have many ***retailer*** s.

Therefore, ***store*** is a **ForeignKey** in my ***retailer*** model. I have registered models in django admin. When I add a retailer I can choose a store. 
When I add a store, I would like to be able to add a retailer to a store in the same page I add a store.

```
class Retailer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=00000000000)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_visitors = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your models (and Django admins, etc.)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the question. Model codes are available now.

Answer (score 0):

it is called inline models:

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/edit_multiple_models.html
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

And you can find a lot of material about,

But you need something like this:
on your admin.py

```
#Create a class for inline display:
class RetailerINLINE(admin.TabularInline): #or stacked inline
    model = Retailer
    extra = 1


class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .....
    inlines = RetailerINLINE,
```